# Problem with bumper buttons on Xbox One wireless Controller?

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, xbox-one

I bought a new Xbox One wireless controller from  [here](http://www.amazon.in/Xbox-Wireless-Controller-Bluetooth-Black/dp/B06X92RN9D?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00). The problem is that when I press either of bumper buttons I feel (little but observable) outward pressure on other bumper, as if they are internally connected. As this is the first time I have bought a Xbox Controller I want to know is this normal for Xbox One controller or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller was defective and now it has been replaced and there is no such problem with new one.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, don't worry, this is completely normal for this controller. In between the left and right bumper is a long, thin cable connecting the two and it's the reason you can feel one bumper being depressed while touching the other bumper.